# New version of API for getting share statistics?

Tags: linkedin-api

I've been using the Organization Share Statistics endpoint to get information about metrics for organic posts. But since it's being sunset, I'm confused what I should be using in its place.

I'm aware of the new /posts endpoint as a potential replacement, however it doesn't look like it returns post statistics -- just metadata if anything.